# Send ADB command to android device with Python while connected with Scrcpy

Tags: python, adb

I am running [QtScrcpy](https://github.com/barry-ran/QtScrcpy) to mirror and control multiple android devices from PC (win). In the same time running Python script which remote stepper motors (turntable). What I need is to send command `adb shell input keyevent 24` to android devices via Python somehow.

Comment: adb (in difference to MTP) allows multiple connections at the same time. So opening an adb shell and sending the key event sending while scrcpy is connected is no problem.

Comment: thank you for answer - but I am not programmer and struggling to create correct code to send the key event to multiple devices

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and create a script like this (this is a minimalistic version)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()[0].press('VOLUME_UP')
```